# Given an offline code from a google oauth request, how can I get google calendar information with node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I used the frontend flow to with:

```
      let { code } = await this.auth2.grantOfflineAccess({
        prompt: "select_account"
      });
```

I have that code and I want to then get access to a users calendar. I tried:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const googleCalendar = google.calendar('v3')
let calendarList = await googleCalendar.calendarList.list({
  auth: code
})
```

But that doesn't seem to work. So how would I use the offline `code` to get calendar information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to use the Calendar API using the access token retrieved with the authorization code.
- You have already been able to use Calendar API, and also retrieve the authorization code.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? At first, please retrieve the access token using the authorization code. Then, you can use the API using the access token.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows. Before you use this script, please set the variables of `code`, `client_id`, `client_secret` and `redirect_uris`.

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')

// Please set the following variables.
const code = "###";
const client_id = "###";
const client_secret = "###";
const redirect_uris = "###";

// Retrieve access token.
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  client_id,
  client_secret,
  redirect_uris
);
const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

// Use Calendar API
const googleCalendar = google.calendar({ version: "v3" });
let calendarList = await googleCalendar.calendarList.list({
  auth: oauth2Client
});
console.log(calendarList.data);
```

#### Note:

- The authorization code can be used only one time. So please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Retrieve access token](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client#retrieve-access-token)

If I misunderstood your question and this wat not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Why do I need a redirect_uri if I’m doing all the processing server side?

Comment: @Shamoon When `redirect_uri` is not set, an error occurs. So I think that this is the specification of Google side. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, for example, how about using `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`, `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto` and `http://localhost` as `redirect_uri`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps?hl=en#obtainingaccesstokens) If this was not useful for your situation, I apologize.